# remove multiple consecutive occurrences of .* in a string with a single .* python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Below is my code to check for the multiple consecutive occurrences of  `".*"`
in string. If there are multiple consecutive occurrences of `".*"` then replace it with single `".*"`. Forg:

```
import re

dot_star_check = re.compile('(\.\*){2,}')

k = ".*.*.*.*.*foo.*"

k = k.replace(?,".*") if dot_star_check.search(k) else k

print k
```

What i should write instead of ? to replace multiple consecutive occurrences of `.*` with single `.*`

So, expected output is `.*foo.*`

other egs:

1.) `foo.*.*.*.*bar.* ->foo.*bar.*`

2.) `.*foobar.*.*.*.*.* ->.*foobar.*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` and `(?:\.\*)+` as your pattern:

```
import re
dot_star_check = re.compile('(?:\.\*)+')
k = ".*.*.*.*.*foo.*"
k = re.sub(dot_star_check,'.*',k)

print (k)
```

Prints:

```
.*foo.*
```

You could additionally improve the efficiency of the pattern so that substitution is performed only when there are 2 or more occurences using `(?:\.\*){2,}` :

```
import re
dot_star_check = re.compile('(?:\.\*){2,}')
k = ".*.*.*.*.*foo.*"
k = re.sub(dot_star_check,'.*',k)

print (k)
```

Prints:

```
.*foo.*
```

Comment: why u have ? and : at the start?

Comment: It is a non capturing group. Using a non capturing group is generally more efficient than using a capturing group.

Comment: multiple consecutive occureences of .* is equivalent to single .* right?

Comment: I am not sure I follow, could you please clarify? What do you mean by your comment?

Comment: I am trying to look for data matching patterns -> .*.*.*.*foo.*.* or  bar.*.*.*foo.*.*.* or anything else ; so instead of making a search with the above regexp strings; i am removing multiple consecutive .* with single .*? so , i am asking if there is any difference between .*.*.*.*foo.*.* and .*foo.* or not? I am doing this to make search efficient

Comment: Yes, your edits make sense ; but what i meant to ask is ->  .*.*.*.*foo.*.* =  .*foo.* ? like both with result in same set of data right when i am trying to look for  data matching .*.*.*.*foo.*.* or .*foo.* in sql or elastic search  or any database?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `re.sub` and `(\.\*)+` as your regex:

```
s = 'foo.*.*.*.*bar.*'
s2 = '.*foobar.*.*.*.*.* '
k = ".*.*.*.*.*foo.*"

>>> re.sub('(\.\*)+','.*',s)
'foo.*bar.*'
>>> re.sub('(\.\*)+','.*',s2)
'.*foobar.* '
>>> re.sub('(\.\*)+','.*',k)
'.*foo.*'
```

Comment: Using a character set in this case is not correct, since it would also match `*.` for instance rather than `.*`.